# Upgrading from Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.0.0 to 2.1.2 Foreign Key Issue

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a project that I upgraded from Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.0.0 to 2.1.2

I have two classes directly referencing each other with a virtual link.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}


public class Account
{
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And this was working fine, but after upgrading I receive the following error:

> - $exception  {System.InvalidOperationException: The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'User.Account' and 'Account.User'. To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.

So in my DataContext I set the foreign keys by adding

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {    
     builder.Entity<User>().HasOne(e => e.Account).WithOne(e => e.User).HasForeignKey<Account>(e => e.Id).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

This allows the program to compile and run, but whenever I reference User, Account is null and vice versa. I am not sure why I need to explicitly map my foreign key now since it wasn't necessary before upgrading, or even know to get it to work properly now.

Comment: As the error message indicates, you *have* to explicitly map the FK. It doesn't matter what was before - the fact is that now it is required. What about `null` values, are you using (enabled) *lazy loading* or  *explicit loading* via `Include` when retrieving entities from the db?

Comment: I am using `Include` , I think what is throwing me is when this database/entity was created it auto inserted a relation for AccountId and UserId that I cannot explicitly reference in my `HasForeignKey` since it is not part of the model.

Comment: You can still reference the shadow properties by name, e.g.  `.HasForeignKey<Account>("UserId")`

Comment: @IvanStoev, thank you that worked.